# Netbeans Maven project: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, maven-2, netbeans-platform

I have a NetBeans Platform project build with Maven2. When I try to create a new platform module I get this strange error:

```
cd ~/src; JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java ~/netbeans-7.3/java/maven/bin/mvn -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes...
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java/bin/java
```

In `~/.bashrc` I have definition of `JAVA_HOME`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0"
export JDK_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0"
```

There's no slash at the end, however maven appends `/bin/java/bin/java` to this path. I can build already existing module with Maven without problems, just when creating a new one it fails. Where does Maven get this `JAVA_HOME`?

**EDIT:**
maven settings:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 21:16:01+0200)
Java version: 1.7.0_17
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.2.0-39-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

Comment: Are you using `Open JDK` or `Oracle/Sun JDK`?

Comment: It's Oracle Java, but it doesn't matter in this case. Yes, problem is in NetBeans I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with incorrect definition of `JAVA_HOME` in `~/.bash_profile`

NetBeans integration of maven prefers:

```
System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
```

before:

```
System.getProperty("java.home")
```

Comment: So, what is the correct value for JAVA_HOME? I face the same problem. Actually i set JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_75". When i run `which java ` its value is `/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java`. Maven works well for all my project except when i try maven release plugin for svn.

Comment: I guess when `JAVA_HOME` is unset it might be autodetected. Or try using the one from maven: `mvn -version | grep "Java home"`

Answer (score 1):

You're redefining `JAVA_HOME` on the command line to point to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java`, which is wrong:

```
cd ~/src; JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java ...
```

Remove the `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java` from the command line:

```
cd ~/src; ~/netbeans-7.3/java/maven/bin/mvn -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes...
```

Comment: Yes, I know. That command is generated by the IDE. I supposed it should take the path from `$JAVA_HOME` system variable, but obviously it's not true. It must be overridden by some other settings. Some Maven config maybe?

Comment: @Tombart you're saying it is generated by the ide, so it is not related to maven or maven configs. The problem is either in netbeans or netbeans maven integration

Comment: yeah, seems like NetBeans error. It uses different paths for creating new project and for compiling existing one

Comment: That would suggest you have somehow defined a JDK to be used with the project's actions and your definition is wrong. You can verify that theory by creating a new, clean maven project in some temporary location and try running a build on it..

Comment: if it's the non-project build that's failing to set the right JDK, then it basically boils down to System.getProperty("java.home") or System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") when the env var is preferred if exists..

Answer (score 0):

netbeans takes the JAVA_HOME from the definition of the Java Platform in the IDE (See Tools/Java Platforms)

unless you select a custom platform, IDE uses the default one which is the one the IDE is running on.

All platforms need to be defined in the Tools/Java Platforms dialog and validation checks are in place to select the right folder.

Maybe something changed in time for you and the definition there is not correct?

Comment: You might be right, I've installed recently java7 from apt repository. But the platform is using `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java` which is also the default version. In some cases also used with the maven integration... which is strange :(

Comment: Ok, I've double checked the code, here's how JAVA_HOME is set. First we check Env.JAVA_HOME property in your action defition, if defined we use as is. Otherwise we check the JavaPlatforms from the IDE and match the platform's "java" tool path against the known install folders. Not sure how these match for OS (linux) installed packages, maybe they don't. If they don't, we check the environment variables and use JAVA_HOME from there, If not defined, the point of last resort is the java.home system variable.

Comment: Where is `Env.JAVA_HOME` defined? In `netbeans.conf` I have this: `netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"`

Comment: Env.JAVA_HOME would in your project's Properties/Actions panel (or technically in the ${basedir}/nbactions.xml file.

Comment: I couldn't find any `nbactions.xml` file. I'm creating a new project, so it should be affected by global settings of NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

for linux find the mvn executalble file under netbeans's java/maven/bin folder and add

```
from="/bin/bin/java"
to="/bin/java"
JAVACMD="${JAVACMD/$from/$to}"
```

before the lines

```
if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  echo "Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly."
```

cheers